# How to handle 2 process at once but still responsive gui java

Tags: java, client-server

So i making a program that have gui and can be client/server at same time but my program only process one progress for example as a server wait for client to connect and wait for it but after that my program is freeze

```
This is server 

public void server(int port) {
        try {
            try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port)) {
                serverStatus = ("Server telah dimulai di port " + port);

                while (true) {
                    // Menunggu koneksi dari client
                    serverStatus = ("Menunggu koneksi dari client...");
                    Socket robot = server.accept();
                    serverStatus = ("Terhubung");
               

                    // Menambahkan koneksi client ke daftar koneksi
                    robotSockets.add(robot);

                    // Membuat thread untuk menangani setiap koneksi client
                    Thread robotThread = new Thread(new ClientHandler(robot));
                    robotThread.start();
                }
            }
```

Here for client

```
public void client(Consumer<String> onMessageReceived) {
        Thread clientSideThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    onMessageReceived.accept(message);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (!socket.isClosed()) {
                    this.statusKoneksi = "Terputus";
                }
            }
        });
        clientSideThread.start();
    }
```

So how to make this program can handle be server and client but still working responsive?, as server wait client to connect and at same time as client can connect to server?

Comment: Before posting here, read [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) provided by Oracle free of cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different threads.

One thread is listen for the socket connection, another is doing other GUI tasks.